How to connect to MySQL server that requires ssh tunnel from Kubernetes pod?
I would like to know which is the best way to reach a MySQL database that is behind a ssh server.
So from DataGrip or DBeaver I need to use a ssh server to be inside the network to reach MySQL endpoint.
Now I'm trying to run Trino locally using Kind/Kubectl and I would like to reach the MySQL server.
How can I instruct K8s to use a similar approach or forward the connectivity using the ssh tunnel I already have for mentioned applications?
Thanks.

Change the networking layer to allow remote access to your Kubernetes Nodes' "egress address(es)". Sometimes referred to as "punching a hole in the firewall," this simple fix is not always recommended. To create a "tunneled" connection between your node(s) and the database server, create an SSH tunnel with port forwarding. This connection is prone to recoverability issues and network connectivity issues, making it unreliable.

Establish a VPN client (which may also be done with openvpn) inside the node's POD subnet. This setup is dependable, secure, manageable, and long-lasting. Openvpn can be installed on the database server or any other node inside the same subnet. A comprehensive, documented end-to-end example may be found at OpenVPN @ Kubernetes, Secure LAN access. Keep it buttoned up!.

Thanks, I was looking for something to do within the cluster itself rather than modifying the mysql server.

you can use socat with nohup linux command on your bastion which will redirect your traffic to MySQL server.
nohup socat TCP4-LISTEN:3306,fork TCP4:<your_mysql_server:3306> & cat nohup.out
In trino config, you can put the bastion address:3306. You traffic will reach to the mysql.

Thanks, I was able to achieve the desired output using a command similar as below: ssh -N -g -L 0.0.0.0:3306:mysqlendpoint:3306 -i /Users/path/.ssh/id_ed25519 ubuntu@jump_server
